# the sum of the series $\sum \frac{n}{2^{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis

the sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n}}$ is 1. It is easy to find since it is a g.p.  the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^{n}}$ is convergent by ratio test. How will find the infinite sum? I am  trying to rearrange the terms and to use the rearrangement theorem, but I can't complete

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-evaluate-the-sum-of-n-2-n-from-n-1-to-infinity

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Use that $\sum_{n=0} nx^{n-1}=(\sum_{n=0} x^n)'=(\frac{1}{1-x})'$ for $x=\frac{1}{2}$.